# Apache Beam - Integration test with unbounded PCollection

Tags: java, integration-testing, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub, apache-beam

We are building an integration test for an Apache Beam pipeline and are running into some issues. See below for context...

Details about our pipeline:

- We use `PubsubIO` as our data source (unbounded `PCollection`)
- Intermediate transforms include a custom `CombineFn` and a very simple windowing/triggering strategy
- Our final transform is `JdbcIO`, using `org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver` to write to Neo4j

Current testing approach:

- Run Google Cloud's Pub/Sub emulator on the machine that the tests are running on
- Build an in-memory Neo4j database and pass its URI into our pipeline options
- Run pipeline by calling `OurPipeline.main(TestPipeline.convertToArgs(options)`
- Use Google Cloud's Java Pub/Sub client library to publish messages to a test topic (using Pub/Sub emulator), which `PubsubIO` will read from
- Data should flow through the pipeline and eventually hit our in-memory instance of Neo4j
- Make simple assertions regarding the presence of this data in Neo4j

This is intended to be a simple integration test which will verify that our pipeline as a whole is behaving as expected.

The issue we're currently having is that when we run our pipeline it is blocking. We are using `DirectRunner` and `pipeline.run()` (**not** `pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish()`), but the test seems to hang after running the pipeline. Because this is an unbounded `PCollection` (running in streaming mode), the pipeline does not terminate, and thus any code after it is not reached.

So, I have a few questions:

1) Is there a way to run a pipeline and then stop it manually later?

2) Is there a way to run a pipeline asynchronously? Ideally it would just kick off the pipeline (which would then continuously poll Pub/Sub for data) and then move on to the code responsible for publishing to Pub/Sub.

3) Is this method of integration testing a pipeline reasonable, or are there better methods that might be more straightforward? Any info/guidance here would be appreciated.

Let me know if I can provide any additional code/context - thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can run the pipeline asynchronously using the `DirectRunner`  by passing setting the `isBlockOnRun` pipeline option to `false`. So long as you keep a reference to the returned `PipelineResult` available, calling `cancel()` on that result should stop the pipeline.

For your third question, your setup seems reasonable. However, if you want to have a smaller-scale test of your pipeline (requiring fewer components), you can encapsulate all of your processing logic within a custom `PTransform`. This `PTransform` should take inputs that have been fully parsed from an input source, and produce outputs that are yet to be parsed for the output sink.

When this is done, you can use either `Create` (which will generally not exercise triggering) or `TestStream` (which may, depending on how you construct the `TestStream`) with the `DirectRunner` to generate a finite amount of input data, apply this processing `PTransform` to that `PCollection`, and use `PAssert` on the output `PCollection` to verify that the pipeline generated the outputs which you expect.

For more information about testing, the Beam website has information about these styles of tests in the [Programming Guide](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/pipelines/test-your-pipeline/) and a [blog post](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2016/10/20/test-stream.html) about testing pipelines with `TestStream`.